# Powershell Chart

Tags: powershell, charts

I'm using PowerShell V5, and my trying to create charts based on the command "out-chart". I've googled so, that I do not want to reinvent the wheel, but the result haven't worked as I assume the syntax are for older version.

Any tutorial or guidance for new version? What should be the "InputObject", "Groupinfo"?

```
NAME
    Out-Chart

SYNTAX
    Out-Chart -InputObject <psobject[]> -GroupInfo <GroupInfo[]> [-ChartSettings <ChartSettings>] [-XLabel <string>] [-YLabel <string[]>] [-Width <int>] [-Height <int>] [-Title <string>] [-Path <string>] [-ForceForm] [-Enable3D] [-SeriesColor <KnownColor[]> {ActiveBorder | ActiveCaption | ActiveCaptionText | AppWorkspace | Control | ControlDark | ControlDarkDark | ControlLight | ControlLightLight | ControlText | Desktop | GrayText | Highlight
    | HighlightText | HotTrack | InactiveBorder | InactiveCaption | InactiveCaptionText | Info | InfoText | Menu | MenuText | ScrollBar | Window | WindowFrame | WindowText | Transparent | AliceBlue | AntiqueWhite | Aqua | Aquamarine | Azure | Beige | Bisque | Black | BlanchedAlmond | Blue | BlueViolet | Brown | BurlyWood | CadetBlue | Chartreuse | Chocolate | Coral | CornflowerBlue | Cornsilk | Crimson | Cyan | DarkBlue | DarkCyan |
    DarkGoldenrod | DarkGray | DarkGreen | DarkKhaki | DarkMagenta | DarkOliveGreen | DarkOrange | DarkOrchid | DarkRed | DarkSalmon | DarkSeaGreen | DarkSlateBlue | DarkSlateGray | DarkTurquoise | DarkViolet | DeepPink | DeepSkyBlue | DimGray | DodgerBlue | Firebrick | FloralWhite | ForestGreen | Fuchsia | Gainsboro | GhostWhite | Gold | Goldenrod | Gray | Green | GreenYellow | Honeydew | HotPink | IndianRed | Indigo | Ivory | Khaki |
    Lavender | LavenderBlush | LawnGreen | LemonChiffon | LightBlue | LightCoral | LightCyan | LightGoldenrodYellow | LightGray | LightGreen | LightPink | LightSalmon | LightSeaGreen | LightSkyBlue | LightSlateGray | LightSteelBlue | LightYellow | Lime | LimeGreen | Linen | Magenta | Maroon | MediumAquamarine | MediumBlue | MediumOrchid | MediumPurple | MediumSeaGreen | MediumSlateBlue | MediumSpringGreen | MediumTurquoise | MediumVioletRed |
    MidnightBlue | MintCream | MistyRose | Moccasin | NavajoWhite | Navy | OldLace | Olive | OliveDrab | Orange | OrangeRed | Orchid | PaleGoldenrod | PaleGreen | PaleTurquoise | PaleVioletRed | PapayaWhip | PeachPuff | Peru | Pink | Plum | PowderBlue | Purple | Red | RosyBrown | RoyalBlue | SaddleBrown | Salmon | SandyBrown | SeaGreen | SeaShell | Sienna | Silver | SkyBlue | SlateBlue | SlateGray | Snow | SpringGreen | SteelBlue | Tan | Teal
    | Thistle | Tomato | Turquoise | Violet | Wheat | White | WhiteSmoke | Yellow | YellowGreen | ButtonFace | ButtonHighlight | ButtonShadow | GradientActiveCaption | GradientInactiveCaption | MenuBar | MenuHighlight}] [-ChartType <SeriesChartType> {Point | FastPoint | Bubble | Line | Spline | StepLine | FastLine | Bar | StackedBar | StackedBar100 | Column | StackedColumn | StackedColumn100 | Area | SplineArea | StackedArea | StackedArea100
    | Pie | Doughnut | Stock | Candlestick | Range | SplineRange | RangeBar | RangeColumn | Radar | Polar | ErrorBar | BoxPlot | Renko | ThreeLineBreak | Kagi | PointAndFigure | Funnel | Pyramid}] [-Clipboard]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Out-Chart -InputObject <psobject[]> -Property <string[]> [-ChartSettings <ChartSettings>] [-XLabel <string>] [-YLabel <string[]>] [-Width <int>] [-Height <int>] [-Title <string>] [-Path <string>] [-ForceForm] [-Enable3D] [-SeriesColor <KnownColor[]> {ActiveBorder | ActiveCaption | ActiveCaptionText | AppWorkspace | Control | ControlDark | ControlDarkDark | ControlLight | ControlLightLight | ControlText | Desktop | GrayText | Highlight |
    HighlightText | HotTrack | InactiveBorder | InactiveCaption | InactiveCaptionText | Info | InfoText | Menu | MenuText | ScrollBar | Window | WindowFrame | WindowText | Transparent | AliceBlue | AntiqueWhite | Aqua | Aquamarine | Azure | Beige | Bisque | Black | BlanchedAlmond | Blue | BlueViolet | Brown | BurlyWood | CadetBlue | Chartreuse | Chocolate | Coral | CornflowerBlue | Cornsilk | Crimson | Cyan | DarkBlue | DarkCyan |
    DarkGoldenrod | DarkGray | DarkGreen | DarkKhaki | DarkMagenta | DarkOliveGreen | DarkOrange | DarkOrchid | DarkRed | DarkSalmon | DarkSeaGreen | DarkSlateBlue | DarkSlateGray | DarkTurquoise | DarkViolet | DeepPink | DeepSkyBlue | DimGray | DodgerBlue | Firebrick | FloralWhite | ForestGreen | Fuchsia | Gainsboro | GhostWhite | Gold | Goldenrod | Gray | Green | GreenYellow | Honeydew | HotPink | IndianRed | Indigo | Ivory | Khaki |
    Lavender | LavenderBlush | LawnGreen | LemonChiffon | LightBlue | LightCoral | LightCyan | LightGoldenrodYellow | LightGray | LightGreen | LightPink | LightSalmon | LightSeaGreen | LightSkyBlue | LightSlateGray | LightSteelBlue | LightYellow | Lime | LimeGreen | Linen | Magenta | Maroon | MediumAquamarine | MediumBlue | MediumOrchid | MediumPurple | MediumSeaGreen | MediumSlateBlue | MediumSpringGreen | MediumTurquoise | MediumVioletRed |
    MidnightBlue | MintCream | MistyRose | Moccasin | NavajoWhite | Navy | OldLace | Olive | OliveDrab | Orange | OrangeRed | Orchid | PaleGoldenrod | PaleGreen | PaleTurquoise | PaleVioletRed | PapayaWhip | PeachPuff | Peru | Pink | Plum | PowderBlue | Purple | Red | RosyBrown | RoyalBlue | SaddleBrown | Salmon | SandyBrown | SeaGreen | SeaShell | Sienna | Silver | SkyBlue | SlateBlue | SlateGray | Snow | SpringGreen | SteelBlue | Tan | Teal
    | Thistle | Tomato | Turquoise | Violet | Wheat | White | WhiteSmoke | Yellow | YellowGreen | ButtonFace | ButtonHighlight | ButtonShadow | GradientActiveCaption | GradientInactiveCaption | MenuBar | MenuHighlight}] [-ChartType <SeriesChartType> {Point | FastPoint | Bubble | Line | Spline | StepLine | FastLine | Bar | StackedBar | StackedBar100 | Column | StackedColumn | StackedColumn100 | Area | SplineArea | StackedArea | StackedArea100
    | Pie | Doughnut | Stock | Candlestick | Range | SplineRange | RangeBar | RangeColumn | Radar | Polar | ErrorBar | BoxPlot | Renko | ThreeLineBreak | Kagi | PointAndFigure | Funnel | Pyramid}] [-Clipboard]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```

Comment: Question is off-topic, where does your cmdlet stem from - ask the author.

Comment: @LotPings refer cmdlet

Comment: Based on the help output this looks like [powercode's `PSChart` module](https://github.com/powercode/PSChart/) - the github readme page shows and example of creating a column chart using the second parameter set. If you want help with a specific situation/chart, please specify exactly _what_ you're trying to achieve and what you've tried so far

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link @MathiasR.Jessen , it was a good start for me. I'm trying to achieve "How to properly use out-chart syntax ?" to create required charts.